# Convertir la siguiente linea de jquery a angular (addClass and removeClass)

Tags: jquery, angularjs

necesito convertir las siguientes lineas (que al darle click verifica cual es la clase activa y cambia de acuerdo a cual sea..)
Desde ya muchas gracias.

```js
$(".x-navigation-minimize").click(function() {
  if ($(".page-sidebar .x-navigation").hasClass("x-navigation-minimized")) {
    $(".page-container").removeClass("page-navigation-toggled");
    $(".page-container").removeClass("page-container-wide");
    $(".page-sidebar .x-navigation").removeClass("x-navigation-minimized");
    $(".x-navigation-minimize").find(".fa").removeClass("fa-indent").addClass("fa-dedent");
  } else {
    $(".page-container").addClass("page-navigation-toggled");
    $(".page-container").addClass("page-container-wide");
    $(".page-sidebar .x-navigation").addClass("x-navigation-minimized");
    $(".x-navigation-minimize").find(".fa").removeClass("fa-dedent").addClass("fa-indent");
  }
});
```

Comment: Buenas, probaste usando ng-class? Lo que hace esta directiva es verificar el estado de una variable, y en consecuencia agregar o quitar una clase. En caso de que este acercamiento te sea útil, puedo armar un ejemplo en plunker.

Comment: muchas gracias lo probare ahora

Comment: probe y no encuentro manera de aplicarlo con un solo boton. (tengo un solo boton y de acuerdo a el estilo que tiene deberia aplicar el inverso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La libreria de angular cuenta con jqlite, lo puedes acceder con la sentencia `angular.element` te dejo un ejemplo mas completo.

```
angular.element('#div1').addClass("alpha");
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado con toggleClass

```js
this.toggleBar = function() {
  var container = angular.element(document.querySelector('.page-container'));
  var bar = angular.element(document.querySelector('.page-sidebar .x-navigation'));
  container.toggleClass('page-navigation-toggled');
  container.toggleClass('page-container-wide');
  bar.toggleClass('x-navigation-minimized');
}
```